# Create a virtual board as often seen on YouTube

Tags: computer-engineering, computer-hardware

I have seen a lot of YouTube videos that use a virtual board for teaching. For example, in the video link below, how can I do the same thing? What are the steps in details in order to be able to create a board as has been done by this professor?

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HAPTxiRIZMg

Any help will be very appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This appears to be UV florescent ink, on glass. Have a look at 2min32s when he smudges it with his fingers. In addition, mirroring the video L/R then corrects the fact you are looking at the back of the text, fixing the mirror writing you would otherwise see.

Comment: Thank you. Exactly I see!